# How to set DNS1 and DNS2 in Android Programmatically & How to check DNS is set or not?

Tags: android, android-studio, dns, wifi, vpn

I try some codes for DNS

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_USE_STATIC_IP, "1");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1, "8.8.4.4");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS2, "8.8.8.8");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_GATEWAY, "192.168.0.1");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_NETMASK, "255.255.255.0");
    android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_IP, "192.168.1.51");
```

But this code isn't working.

if this code is working then where I check DNS is set.

Anyone please help me with how to deal with DNS.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the 'WRITE_SETTINGS' permission in your 'AndroidManifest.xml':

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Check user permission and if it granted you can change settings:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
            android.provider.Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1, "8.8.8.8");
        }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + this.getPackageName()));
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

and you can read what you set as follows:

```
String dns1 = Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(),  Settings.System.WIFI_STATIC_DNS1);
```

Comment: I already add this permission. I asked about how to check value after a set value. Value is set or not.